# Don't show object when relations is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

the relationships are:

```
class apartment 
  belongs_to :house
end

class house
  has_many :apartments
end
```

In the index method of my apartment controller I find all the houses with `houses.all`. 
In the view there is a block of houses with the right (has_many) apartments

Issue:

There are houses with no apartments and I don't want to show these houses on my apartment page. How can I realize this?

Comment: Yes, you have to accept answer when we solve your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in several way, when you enumerate this :

```
for house in houses
   if house.appartments.count > 0
     puts house.title
   end
 end
```

Or when you get your datas using a scope :

```
scope :with_appartments, lambda { joins(:appartments).group('appartments.id').uniq { |h| h[:id] }  }
myHousesWithAppartments = House.with_appartemnts
```

Or you can use a counter cache : http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: looks very logical, but i got this message > syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'

Comment: sebastian..thanks for the quick reply. But now i got the error message ArgumentError in AppartmentsController#index

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)


app/models/house.rb:6:in `block in <class:House>'
app/controllers/appartments_controller.rb:34:in `index

Comment: I edited my code, and i tested on my project. It seems to work.

Comment: thanks...getting close now. It works but i got multply houses...so instead of 1 i got 2.

Comment: These houses have appartments?

Comment: yep...the houses with no apartments are gone!

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use named scope in your house model, something like this:

```
scope :filled, :joins => :apartments
```

And in controller action you must call House.filled

Here is solution with select method:

```
House.select {|house| house.apartments.any?}
```

Comment: looks very logical, but i got this message > syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `'empty?'` method:

```
<% if !(@house.apartments.empty?) %>
  <% @house.apartments.each do |aprtmt|
    <%= aprtmt.info %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is the easiest way to see it.  Proper Rails says you should put your logic in the controller, not the view.  So a more appropriate implementation would be in your Houses#Show controller action:

```
@houses = House.all
@houses_with_apartments = []
@houses.each do |house|
  @houses_with_apartments << house unless house.empty?
end
```

Then in your view you use the @houses_with_apartments variable.

Hope this helps.